Event Bridge Contact Events AWS Connect Integration
I recently started up an AWS Connect instance from a cloud formation. I want to route the call events to a web server, where I can process each event in real-time and display it to my web app. Here is the general structure:
API Gateway:

I have endpoints to $connect, $disconnect, and ping.
I use dynamoDB to dynamically add all the current web socket connection ids (to-be used by the event bridge)

Web server:

Flask app listening for events from the websocket.

Event Bridge:

I have an aws connect rule setup to send all Amazon Connect Contact Events to a lamda function. The lamda function reads the event, and sends the event to all the web socket connections using the dynamoDB to get the connection ids.

AWS Connect:

My inbound call flow configuration is fairly trivial, with a lambda invocation that prints the Contact Flow Events, which includes the caller number (this is important).

Question: The AWS Connect lambda invocation function is receiving the Contact Flow Events with caller number data, but how do I use that caller number data in the Event Bridge rule lambda function? Is there an easy way to associate the two? Technically, because both events share a "contactId" key, I can dump contact flow events into a dynamo db table with short expiration, and retrieve it from the Amazon Connect Contact Event based on the contactId, but is there a more straightforward, lower latency solution? Thanks for the read :)

Sounds a bit costly. What’s the role of websocket? Who is the subscriber- is a webserver or a client browser?

@gamliela the webserver the websocket will be used on is a flask server i already used to integrate with other VOIP call services. Processing it on the web server will allow me to centralize logging and business logic. The subscriber is a python instance. Web server costs ~$10 monthly, kinesis data stream is cheap for the text transmission I'm doing, and Lambda functions run for milliseconds.

I meant there might be an extra step. Couldn’t you hook EventBridge to the python server directly?

As the event data from Connect contains both the ContactID and the Instance ARN, the lambda function called by event bridge can call GetContactAttributes to get the call attributes, including the callers phone number.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_GetContactAttributes.html
